# Using jQuery before() with jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to use the jQuery before() with JQuery 1.3.2, is this possible?

I have a div like this:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      CONTENT HERE
 </div>
```

That I would like to use jQuery before() to add a container around it.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div id="wrapper">
           CONTENT HERE
      </div>
 </div>
```

I do not have access to the HTML, this is in a SaaS platform that determines all of that stuff. So, using jQuery to insert a new div around the wrapper seems like the way to go.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `.wrap()` instead of `.before()`...

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 is very old; it was released over two years before IE 9 was released.

Comment: You can use `$('#wrapper').wrap('<div class="container"></div>')` - available since version 1.0

Comment: `before()` was added in jQuery 1.0. It should work in 1.3.2. It's just not the correct function for what you want, as the other comments point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the jquery[`.wrap` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('#wrapper').wrap('<div class="content"></div>');
```

As mentioned by the others in the comments above.

Comment: Awesome, I've added this to my JS file and wrapped it in document.ready, but I receive the error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function